# How to dynamicly select needed columns in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, multilingual

Heys guys, I have a table with content in different languages. like this:

id, name_en, name_de

Now when I request data with Eloquent I always did this:

```
Product::with(['offers', 'category'])->select(['id', getLocalValue('name'))->find($id);
```

The function getLocalValue is taking the browser-language, selects the current column and gives it back as "name". So when the browser language is english I get data like

```
{"id" => 1,
 "name" => "Englisch name"
}
```

MY PROBLEM: I have lots of multi-language content in lots of tables with relations. And when using the ->select() function i have to put all the columns here I want to request. Actually all I want to do is getting everything. But for data that is in different columns because of multilanguage, it should take the needed column (like name_en) and give it back without the _en (name).

I hope you know what I mean and can help me out here :( Thanks for your time!!! gerti

Comment: This is mainly a problem of data being saved the wrong way. The way you are doing it now, imagine you want to sell in france, too. You'd need to have all your tables changed >>> bad idea. Better make a table for each language, then set the table dynamically. e.g. `de_names` table holds foreign key `id` and `name` only, same goes for the other languages, then simply pick them

Comment: Well I know what you mean thank you! But how and when do I choose the right translation-table? Should I do it in the model and generate it there dynamicly?

Comment: You can set the table you want to use in your `Product` Model.  I'll post an answer

Comment: I hope I could make clear what I've meant, if not feel free to ask...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above, I'd change the data structure to have the language names in a seperate table by name. Then, if you want to use browser language for detection, you can use this to directly set the table according to the language.

Add this to your `productName` Model:

```
protected static $_table;

public function setTable($prefix)
{
    static::$_table = $prefix.'_productNames';
    return $this;
}

public function getTable()
{
    return static::$_table;
}

public function Product () {
    return $this->belongsTo('Product');
}
```

And add this to your `Product` Model:

```
public function productName () {
    return $this->hasOne('productName');
}
```

Now you can set the table you intend to use by:

```
$productName = new productName;
$productName->setTable(strtolower(getLocalValue('name')));
```

According to this, your table has to be named

```
de_productNames
```

just to give you an example.

Now you can use your query like:

```
$productName = new productName;
$productName->setTable(strtolower(getLocalValue('name'))); 
Product::with(['offers', 'category','productName'])->find($id);
```

I'm not sure what your `getLocalValue()` does, the strtolower is just to fit to the table name, get rid of it if getLocalValue() already does this for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that!! :) I understand how it is working. But it feels kind of weird to have a model for every column that needs to be translated. My application will be kind of large so i would have tons of these models. I will still try to do it your way for now :) Thank you!

Comment: You don't need a model for each column, if you would need for now, change your dataset further to simplify it as much as possible.

Comment: Hmm Sorry i don't know what you mean. As i understand it i would have one table for every column in every language i want it to translate. And also one model for the column. Like you did it above with with the productName Model

Comment: Yes, but you only need one model for all of the product names tables. They will automatically be resolved by the set table method. Just make sure to name all of them prefix_productNames ( e.g. de_productNames, en_productNames,... )@gerti